# Number precision in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

Why 100 == 99.999 is true, however 100 == 99.99 is false in Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you getting that result?

From Firebug console in Firefox 3.6.3

```
>>> 100==99.99
false
>>> 100==99.999
false
>>> 100==99.9999
false
>>> 100==99.99999
false
>>> 100==99.999999
false
>>> 100==99.9999999
false
>>> 100==99.99999999
false
>>> 100==99.999999999
false
>>> 100==99.9999999999
false
>>> 100==99.99999999999
false
>>> 100==99.999999999999
false
>>> 100==99.9999999999999
false
>>> 100==99.99999999999999
false
>>> 100==99.999999999999999
true
```

Comment: @airbai, now you have two problems :)

Answer (score 4):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf)

and the shorter, more to the point:

http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score -3):

> Why is 100 == 99.999 true in Javascript?

It's not; whatever Javascript implementation you are using is buggy.

> however 100 == 99.99 is false in Javascript?

Because they're not equal.